# Remove line breaks in str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying to use a str_replace to remove any occurrences of html in a template that contain:

```
 <br><br style='font-size:10px;'>
 <br><br style='font-size:10px;'>
```

But for the life of me I can't "detect" the line break, even when using \n

```
 $replacestring = "<br><br style='font-size:10px;'>\n<br><br style='font-size:10px;'>";

 $output = str_replace($replacestring, $empty, $output);
```

If I just do one line, it detects it for example:

```
 $replacestring = "<br><br style='font-size:10px;'>";
```

Why is it not detecting the line break? $output is the FINAL html output

Comment: Where does `$empty` come into play?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the str_replace() command shows that the output is the second argument, not the last.

The following example may help you:

```
<?php
 $template_string = "<br><br style='font-size:10px;'>line1\n<br><br style='font-size:10px;'>line2";
 $replace_string = "<br><br style='font-size:10px;'>";
 $output = str_replace($replace_string, $output, $template_string);
 echo $output;
?>
```

The output then shows:

```
line1
line2
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned about performance I would try using preg_replace instead so you can capture strings with multiple line breaks more easily using regular expressions.

Try this:

```
$replacestring="<br><br style='font-size:10px;'>line1\n<br><br style='font-size:10px;'>line2";

$pattern = '/([\\n]+)?\<br([^>]+)?\>/';

echo preg_replace($pattern,'', $replacestring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out another plugin was executing AFTER, so the script was never able to replace properly. Thanks for the help guys